# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-7, tiles-3

I just upgraded a Spring MVC application, version `3.2` to a `4.0.2` and my view tags are not working anymore.

The error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.resolveMessage(MessageTag.java:215)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:166)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
org.apache.jsp.views.templates.main_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(main_jsp.java:570)
```

The class **ExpressionEvaluationUtils** was deprecated in Spring `3.2` and removed in `4.x.`

I'm running Tomcat 7.0.50 using Eclipse IDE.

What am i missing here?

Belo are some parts of my configuration.

```
 <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed you JSPs when upgrading spring then you may have old compiled JSPs from the old spring version (the *.tags.MessageTag.* thing in you stacktrace). Clear your tomcat work directory to recompile the JSPs and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that you need to change the jsp-config `web.xml` to `ignore-el = true`.
It works now.

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>**true**</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update the spring-security dependencies to 4.0.n.RELEASE versions.