# HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, runtime-error

Following this example http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/
I'm facing an error I can't solve.

When I start the server (Tomcat 7) I don't get any errors, but when I run the application on the server in Eclipse I see on the page:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>
> root cause
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspService(contact_jsp.java:89)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.evaluate(AbstractFormTag.java:50)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.resolveModelAttribute(FormTag.java:385)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.autogenerateId(FormTag.java:377)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.writeTagContent(FormTag.java:334)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_jsp.java:111)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspService(contact_jsp.java:79)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.53 logs.
>
> ---
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.53

and in the server console:

> 21-mag-2014 17.21.12 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
>   invoke GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.evaluate(AbstractFormTag.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.resolveModelAttribute(FormTag.java:385)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.autogenerateId(FormTag.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.writeTagContent(FormTag.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_jsp.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspService(contact_jsp.java:79)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
>     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 21-mag-2014 17.21.12
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke GRAVE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.evaluate(AbstractFormTag.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.resolveModelAttribute(FormTag.java:385)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.autogenerateId(FormTag.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.writeTagContent(FormTag.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_jsp.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspService(contact_jsp.java:79)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
>     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 21-mag-2014 17.21.12
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/FormPage]
>   threw exception [org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils] with root
>   cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.evaluate(AbstractFormTag.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.resolveModelAttribute(FormTag.java:385)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.autogenerateId(FormTag.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.writeTagContent(FormTag.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_jsp.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspService(contact_jsp.java:79)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
>     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The libraries I've imported are:

- commons-logging
- jsp
- jstl
- org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1
- spring-aop-4.0.4
- spring-beans-4.0.4
- spring-context-4.0.4
- spring-core-4.0.4
- spring-expression-4.0.4
- sprig-web-4.0.4
- spring-webmvc-4.0.4

I tried to copy the jars in the server folder but nothing has changed.
Any idea?

Comment: See this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231865/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-util-expressionevaluat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231865/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-util-expressionevaluat)

Comment: And you don't need org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1, spring-webmvc-4.0.4 is its Spring 4 equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the suggestions in the link you've shared don't work.

Comment: Then look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547637/alternatives-to-springs-deprecated-expressionevaluationutils-evaluate-methods) and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils.html#isSpringJspExpressionSupportActive%28javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext%29).

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thank you for the link. I don't know exactly how to use the class in the first link. In fact I asked him. But is there any way to avoid this problem using other staff?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I solve it thanks to you! I took off the org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1 that by mistake was within the libraries while I thought I've taken off completely. Tahnk you :)

Comment: @AndreiStefan I think you can answer to the question so I can pick the check for the correct answer.

Comment: There you go. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1, spring-webmvc-4.0.4 is its Spring 4 equivalent.